# How to connect to database automatically?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server 2014 Express and I can't connect to the database using `web.config` in my ASP.NET MVC project.

Name of my server is `MySqlExpress`.

I used this connection string

```
<add name="Context"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\MYSQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

and tried some others, but still get an

> Error 50 - Local Database Runtime Error. Cannot find LocalDB instance. Server is not available or not found

I set up server myself, with integrated security.

I have some other SQL Servers on my machine but the same I can't connect to them through `web.config`, but i can through the server explorer.

Here is my `web.config`, I use Entity Framework + code first strategy

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Context"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
             connectionString="Data Source=.\MYSQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\test.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" 
                     type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider"  
                     type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
                     connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
                     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
                     enablePasswordReset="true" 
                     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
                     requiresUniqueEmail="false"  
                     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
                     minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
                     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
                     passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" 
                     type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
                     connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" 
                     applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
            <providers>
                 <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" 
                      type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
                      connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
             <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
             <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
             <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />

             <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" 
                  path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" 
                  modules="IsapiModule" 
                  scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
                  preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" 
                  responseBufferLimit="0" />
             <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" 
                  path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" 
                  modules="IsapiModule" 
                  scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
                  preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"  
                  responseBufferLimit="0" />
             <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" 
                  path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" 
                  type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
                  preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
         </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
          <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
               <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
               <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0"   newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" 
                                publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages"   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <contexts>
             <context type="test.Models.Context, test">
                 <databaseInitializer type="test.Models.ContextInitializer, test" />
             </context>
        </contexts>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="v13.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up SQL Server Configuration Manager (search for it in the Start menu). Click on SQL Server Services. The instance name of SQL Server is in parenthesis inline with SQL Server service. If it says MSSQLSERVER, then it's the default instance. To connect to it in Management Studio, just type . (dot) OR (local) and click Connect. If the instance name is different, then use .[instance name] to connect to it (for example if the instance name is SQL2008, connect to .\SQL2008).